# How can I add angular custom shield in my sign-up form for my angular firebase database?

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

So I follow one tutorial for creating my angular app with firebase auth.

At the moment, all working.

but

For the first time, I search to create a real sign-up form with custom field and add them into my firebase auth sign-up method

I already edit my existing sign-up form and add my custom-field on him
and try to add my personal "user" interface.

I use angular 7 for my firebase project

```
import { Injectable, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import { User } from "../services/user";
import { auth } from 'firebase/app';
import { AngularFireAuth } from "@angular/fire/auth";
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreDocument } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { Router } from "@angular/router";
@Injectable({
providedIn:'root'
})
export class AuthService {
    userData: any; // Save logged in user data
    constructor(
        private afs: AngularFirestore,   // Inject Firestore service
        private afAuth: AngularFireAuth, // Inject Firebase auth service
        private router: Router,  
        private ngZone: NgZone // NgZone service to remove outside scope warning
    ) {
        this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(user => {
            if(user){
                this.userData = user;
                localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(this.userData));
                JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
            }
            else {
                localStorage.setItem('user', null);
                JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
            } 
        })
    }
    // Sign in with email/password
    SignIn(email, password){
        return this.afAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .then((result) => {
            this.ngZone.run(() => {
                this.router.navigate(['dashboard']);
            });
            this.SetUserData(result.user);
        }).catch((error) =>{
            window.alert(error.message)
        })
    }
    // Sign up with email/password
    SignUp(email, password) {
        return this.afAuth.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .then((result) => {
            /* Call the SendVerificaitonMail() function when new user sign 
            up and returns promise */
            this.SendVerificationMail();
            this.SetUserData(result.user);
        }).catch((error) => {
            window.alert(error.message)
        })
    }
    // Send email verfificaiton when new user sign up
    SendVerificationMail(){
        return this.afAuth.auth.currentUser.sendEmailVerification()
        .then(() => {
            this.router.navigate(['verify-email-address']);
        })
    }
    // Reset Forggot password
    ForgotPassword(passwordResetEmail){
        window.alert('forgot password');
        return this.afAuth.auth.sendPasswordResetEmail(passwordResetEmail)
        .then(() => {
            window.alert('Password reset email sent, check your inbox.');
        }).catch((error) => {
            window.alert(error);
        })
    }
    // Returns true when user is looged in and email is verified
    get isLoggedIn(): boolean {
        const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
        return (user !== null && user.emailVerified !== false) ?true : false;
    }
    // Sign in with Google
    GoogleAuth(){
        return this.AuthLogin(new auth.GoogleAuthProvider());
    }
    // Auth logic to run auth providers
    AuthLogin(provider){
        return this.afAuth.auth.signInWithPopup(provider)
        .then((result) => {
            this.ngZone.run(() => {
                this.router.navigate(['dashboard']);
            })
            this.SetUserData(result.user);
        }).catch((error) => {
            window.alert(error)
        })
    }
    /* Setting up user data when sign in with username/password, 
    sign up with username/password and sign in with social auth  
    provider in Firestore database using AngularFirestore + AngularFirestoreDocument service */
    SetUserData(user){
        const userRef: AngularFirestoreDocument<any> = this.afs.doc('user/${user.uid}');
        const userData: User = {
            uid: user.uid,
            email: user.email,
            displayName: user.displayName,
            photoURL: user.photoURL,
            emailVerified: user.emailVerified,
            // firstName: user.firstName,
            // lastName: user.lastName,
            // birthday: user.birthday,
            // addressOne: user.addressOne,
            // addressTwo: user.addressTwo,
            // zipCode: user.zipCode,
            // city: user.city,
            // phoneOne: user.phoneOne,
            // phoneTwo: user.phoneTwo,
            // profilType: user.profilType,
            // profilPicture: user.profilPicture,
            // admin: user.admin,
            // moderator: user.admin
        }
        return userRef.set(userData, {
            merge: true
        })
    }
    // Sign Out
    SignOut(){
        return this.afAuth.auth.signOut().then(() => {
            localStorage.removeItem('user');
            this.router.navigate(['home']);
        })
    }
}
```

my custom sign-up form

```
<div class="page-heading clearfix asset-bg alt-one">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="heading-text">
      <h1 class="entry-title">Register</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="page-wrap">
  <div class="inner-page-wrap has-no-sidebar no-bottom-spacing no-top-spacing clearfix">
    <div class="page-content clearfix">
      <section class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="blank_spacer col-md-12"></div>
        </div>
      </section>
      <section class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12 register-wrap">    
            <div class="authBlock">
              <h2 class="spb-heading spb-text-heading"><span>Register</span></h2>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name" #userFirstName required>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name" #userLastName required>
              </div>              
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address" #userEmail required>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" #userPwd required>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Address" #userAddressOne required>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Address" #userAddressTwo>
              </div>              
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Zip code" #userZipCode required>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="City" #userCity required>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="tel" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone One" #userPhoneOne required>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="tel" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone Two" #userPhoneTwo>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <select name="" #userProfil required>
                  <option value="">Select your profil type</option>
                  <option value="personnal">Particulier</option>
                  <option value="office">Société</option>
                </select>
              </div>              
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Sign Up" (click)="authService.SignUp(userEmail.value, userPwd.value)">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <span class="or"><span class="orInner">Or</span></span>
              </div>
            <!-- Continue with Google -->
              <div class="form-group">
                <button type="button" class="btn googleBtn" (click)="authService.GoogleAuth()">
                  <i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i>
                Continue with Google
                </button>
              </div>
            <!-- Continue with Facebook -->
              <div class="form-group">
                <button type="button" class="btn facebookBtn" (click)="authService.FacebookAuth()">
                  <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
                Continue with Facebook
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="redirectToLogin">
              <span>Already have an account? <span class="redirect" routerLink="/sign-in">Log In</span></span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

my user.ts interface

```
export interface User {
    uid: string;
    email: string;
    displayName: string;
    photoURL: string;
    emailVerified: boolean;
    // firstName: string;
    // lastName: string;
    // birthday: Date;
    // addressOne: string;
    // addressTwo: string;
    // zipCode: string;
    // city: string;
    // phoneOne: string;
    // phoneTwo: string;
    // profilType: string;
    // profilPicture: string;
    // admin: boolean;
    // moderator: boolean;
 }
```

when I try to register with my custom fields, I have errors into my console panel,

this error: "ERROR in src/app/shared/services/auth.service.ts(112,13): error TS2322: Type '{ uid: any; email: any; displayName: any; photoURL: any; emailVerified: any; firstName: any; lastName: any; birthday: any; addressOne: any; addressTwo: any; zipCode: any; city: any; phoneOne: any; phoneTwo: any; profilType: any; profilPicture: any; admin: any; moderator: any; }' is not assignable to type 'User'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'profilType' does not exist in type 'User'."

So I search to understand how can i implement this custom field into sign-up method

Comment: Thanks for your edit :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your custom properties don't exist on a firebase.UserCredential type that gets returned from the createUserWithEmailAndPassword or the built in signIn methods.  You'll need to pass your custom data to your auth signUp and/or login methods, preserve it, then pass it on to your SetUserData method.

Here is something that should work:

### auth.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import { User } from "../services/user";
import { auth } from 'firebase/app';
import { AngularFireAuth } from "@angular/fire/auth";
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreDocument } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { Router } from "@angular/router";
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
@Injectable({
providedIn:'root'
})
export class AuthService {
    userData: any; // Save logged in user data
    user: Observable<User>;
    constructor(
        private afs: AngularFirestore,   // Inject Firestore service
        private afAuth: AngularFireAuth, // Inject Firebase auth service
        private router: Router,  
        private ngZone: NgZone // NgZone service to remove outside scope warning
    ) {
        this.user = this.afAuth.authState.pipe(switchMap(user => {
            if(user){
                this.userData = user;
                localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(this.userData));
                JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
                return this.afs.doc<User>(`users/${user.uid}`).valueChanges();
            }
            else {
                localStorage.setItem('user', null);
                JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
                return of(null);
            } 
        }))
    }
    // Sign in with email/password
    SignIn(email, password){
        return this.afAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .then(() => {
            this.user.subscribe(user => {
              await this.SetUserData(user);
              this.ngZone.run(() => {
                this.router.navigate(['dashboard']);
            });

          });

        }).catch((error) => {
            window.alert(error.message)
        });
    }
    // Sign up with email/password
    SignUp(userData: User) {
        return this.afAuth.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(userData.email, userData.password)
        .then(() => {
            /* Call the SendVerificaitonMail() function when new user sign 
            up and returns promise */
            this.SendVerificationMail();
            this.SetUserData(userData);
        }).catch((error) => {
            window.alert(error.message)
        })
    }
    // Send email verfificaiton when new user sign up
    SendVerificationMail(){
        return this.afAuth.auth.currentUser.sendEmailVerification()
        .then(() => {
            this.router.navigate(['verify-email-address']);
        })
    }
    // Reset Forgot password
    ForgotPassword(passwordResetEmail){
        window.alert('forgot password');
        return this.afAuth.auth.sendPasswordResetEmail(passwordResetEmail)
        .then(() => {
            window.alert('Password reset email sent, check your inbox.');
        }).catch((error) => {
            window.alert(error);
        })
    }
    // Returns true when user is logged in and email is verified
    get isLoggedIn(): boolean {
        const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
        return (user !== null && user.emailVerified !== false) ?true : false;
    }
    // Sign in with Google
    GoogleAuth(userData){
        return this.AuthLogin(new auth.GoogleAuthProvider(), userData);
    }
    // Auth logic to run auth providers
    AuthLogin(provider, userData){
        return this.afAuth.auth.signInWithPopup(provider)
        .then(() => {

            this.SetUserData(userData);
            this.ngZone.run(() => {
              this.router.navigate(['dashboard']);
            })

        }).catch((error) => {
            window.alert(error)
        })
    }
    /* Setting up user data when sign in with username/password, 
    sign up with username/password and sign in with social auth  
    provider in Firestore database using AngularFirestore + AngularFirestoreDocument service */
    SetUserData(user){
        const userRef: AngularFirestoreDocument<any> = this.afs.doc(`user/${user.uid}`);
        const userData: User = {
            uid: user.uid,
            email: user.email,
            displayName: user.displayName,
            photoURL: user.photoURL,
            emailVerified: user.emailVerified,
            firstName: user.firstName,
            lastName: user.lastName,
            birthday: user.birthday,
            addressOne: user.addressOne,
            addressTwo: user.addressTwo,
            zipCode: user.zipCode,
            city: user.city,
            phoneOne: user.phoneOne,
            phoneTwo: user.phoneTwo,
            profilType: user.profilType,
            profilPicture: user.profilPicture,
            admin: user.admin,
            moderator: user.admin
        }
        return userRef.set(userData, {
            merge: true
        })
    }
    // Sign Out
    SignOut(){
        return this.afAuth.auth.signOut().then(() => {
            localStorage.removeItem('user');
            this.router.navigate(['home']);
        })
    }
}
```

I would consider using a form builder in your signup component like such:

### signup.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { AuthService } from 'src/app/core/auth.service'; // Or the path to your Auth Service

@Component({
  selector: 'signup', // Or your signup component selector
  templateUrl: './signup.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./signup.component.scss']
})

export class SignupComponent implements OnInit {

  signUpForm: FormGroup = this.fb.group({
    email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
    password: ['', [Validators.required]],
    displayName: ['', [Validators.required]],
    firstName: ['', [Validators.required]],
    lastName: ['', [Validators.required]],
    addressOne: ['', [Validators.required]],
    addressTwo: [''],
    zipCode: ['', [Validators.required]],
    city: ['', [Validators.required]],
    phoneOne: ['', [Validators.required]],
    phoneTwo: [''],
    profilType: ['', [Validators.required]]
  });

  constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    private auth: AuthService,
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {}

  signUpViaEmail() {
    this.auth.SignUp(this.signUpForm.value);
  }

  googleLogin() {
     this.auth.GoogleAuth(this.signUpForm.value);
  }

}
```

### signup.component.html:

```
<div class="page-heading clearfix asset-bg alt-one">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="heading-text">
      <h1 class="entry-title">Register</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="page-wrap">
  <div class="inner-page-wrap has-no-sidebar no-bottom-spacing no-top-spacing clearfix">
    <div class="page-content clearfix">
      <section class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="blank_spacer col-md-12"></div>
        </div>
      </section>
      <section class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12 register-wrap">    
            <div class="authBlock">
              <h2 class="spb-heading spb-text-heading"><span>Register</span></h2>

              <form [formGroup]="signUpForm" class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name" #userFirstName formControlName="firstName" required>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name" #userLastName formControlName="lastName" required>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Desired Display Name" #displayName formControlName="displayName" required>
              </div>                        
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address" #userEmail formControlName="email" required>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" #userPwd formControlName="password" required>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Address" #userAddressOne formControlName="addressOne" required>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Address" #userAddressTwo formControlName="addressTwo">
              </div>              
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Zip code" #userZipCode formControlName="zipCode" required>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="City" #userCity formControlName="city" required>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="tel" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone One" #userPhoneOne formControlName="phoneOne" required>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="tel" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone Two" #userPhoneTwo formControlName="phoneTwo">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <select name="" #userProfil formControlName="profilType" required>
                  <option value="">Select your profil type</option>
                  <option value="personnal">Particulier</option>
                  <option value="office">Société</option>
                </select>
              </div>              
              <div class="form-group">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="signUpViaEmail()">Sign Up</button>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <span class="or"><span class="orInner">Or</span></span>
              </div>
            <!-- Continue with Google -->
              <div class="form-group">
                <button type="submit" class="btn googleBtn" (click)="googleLogin()">
                  <i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i>
                Continue with Google
                </button>
              </div>
            <!-- Continue with Facebook -->
              <div class="form-group">
                <button type="button" class="btn facebookBtn" (click)="authService.FacebookAuth()">
                  <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
                Continue with Facebook
                </button>
              </div>
            </form>
            <div class="redirectToLogin">
              <span>Already have an account? <span class="redirect" routerLink="/sign-in">Log In</span></span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for your proposal. I have some others questions about my personnal project (new professional website) and want to know if you can help me ? here or in private. Regard

Comment: do you know how can i add to my dashboard view, the user data who are receive to my firestore data ? @gilmourguru

Comment: @elderyn - Are you asking how to get the specific authenticated user's data into their dashboard view, or how you can get all registered firebase users of your app into an admin dashboard that only you can see?